# WPF Datagrid selection issue when getting data async

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a simple datagrid

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgSample" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, IsAsync=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sent" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Sent}" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I populate this datagrid from the Items object

Code behind:

```
    public List<Item> Items { get; set;} 

    private async void GetData()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetItems();
        });
    }

    private void GetItems()
    {
       Items = facade.GetItems();   
    }
```

Everything works fine, I get the data and populate datagrid async. The problem comes when I want to select a row, I can´t. I click on a cell and selection automatically dissapears.

When I populate datagrid sync the problem goes away

Comment: I wouldn't use a `List`, usually you want an `ObservableCollection` bound to the `ItemsSource`. How often do you populate the `Items`? Do you do it on-demand or periodically?

Comment: I populate Items on-demand. Even if I use ObservableCollection the problem persists. Also, I implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so there shouldn't be any problem with List<Item>

Comment: My guess is that you might have another code clearing the selection, because this code you're showing looks good. Are you using any MVVM framework? When you say "When I populate datagrid sync" you mean you load the items async or you remove IsAsync from the binding in xaml?

Comment: For testing purposes I made the wpf window and all the bindings are code behing (no MVVM). By "populating datagrid sync" I mean changing the GetData() method: private void GetData() with no async/await

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [async/await all the way down](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), otherwise you may deadlock the UI thread.

This works for me (I used Prism):

```
using Prism.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ItemsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private MyFacade facade;
    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        facade = new MyFacade();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand GetDataCommand => new DelegateCommand(GetData);

    private async void GetData()
    {
        // it's the best practice to wrap an async void and use an async Task
        await GetItems();
    }

    private async Task GetItems()
    {
        // not really async
        var result =  await facade.GetItems();
        Items.Clear();
        Items.AddRange(result);
    }

    class MyFacade
    {
        public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems()
        {
            // not really async
            var items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Joe", Date = DateTime.Now });
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Bob", Date = DateTime.Now });
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Sam", Date = DateTime.Now });
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataGridPopulatedAsync.Views.ItemsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding GetDataCommand}" Content="Get Data" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```